# How to Run Multiple Gazebo Simulations with Unique Clocks

Tags: ros, gazebo, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a follow on to my previous question: http://answers.ros.org/question/241005/gazebo-topic-publication-issue-within-namespaced-group-tag/

I'm trying to run multiple Gazebo simulations on one machine, using the  tag to encapsulate each simulation within its own namespace.  So far, this works fine.  I'm able to launch the simulations, the robot URDF is loaded and parsed and the simulations proceed.

However, I'm running into one outstanding issue which I am unsure how to/if it can be addressed.  For example, if I run four separate Gazebo simulations, each in their own namespaced group, the /clock topic is not namespaced.  Therefore, each of the four simulations is writing and reading from a common clock leading to synchronization problems and incorrect simulation times.  One simulation might run smoothly, but another might jump around timewise depending on how the underlying operating system schedules the processes.

This leads to wildly unpredictable results and invalid simulations.

Is there a way to place the /clock within the scope of a  tag?  I've been unable to find an example or documentation of this after a fairly comprehensive search.  I'm almost thinking that it is not possible, but will wait for confirmation.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242502/how-to-run-multiple-gazebo-simulations-with-unique-clocks/) by [JaredMoore](https://answers.ros.org/users/26589/jaredmoore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2016-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution should be to use the `<remap>` tag and remap `/clock` per group.  However, on Kinectic there seems to be a problem with this currently. See question http://answers.ros.org/question/242656/is-it-possible-to-remap-clock/ for a detailed look at the problem.

---

Originally posted by [JaredMoore](https://answers.ros.org/users/26589/jaredmoore/) with karma: 71 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0